# Print source code flow as program is executed

Tags: java, debugging

is there a way to print each line of source when the program executes without having to insert System.out.println after each line?

Answer (score 4):

Use a debugger. Debuggers provide a number of useful tools to step through your program. Check your IDE, it probably has one.

Comment: using that a the moment...i have to hit F6 on eclipse to step thru the code each time ..was wondering if i can just print out each line then trace later

Answer (score 1):

First a question: Why would you need that? You might use a debugger if it's just for debugging.
If it is for logging purposes, logging each line would be overkill.

Second a suggestion: you might use AOP to log each method call (assignments etc. could not be intercepted), but that might require a lot of work (incorporate AOP into your build process etc.) and might not be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform Project has a way to show you a sequence diagram of the program execution:

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html

For printing as text, AOP is nice but complicated, debug statements are easiest but most invasive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Eclipse lets you step through the program line by line, the link is unfortunately down for maintenance but maybe check back on it later: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-stepping.htm

Comment: except i have to press F6 for each line executed...thats y i need one that just dumps into a txt file